# enumeration of 3-connected non-isomorphic graphs on 7 vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for an online source (e.g., an article) with an enumeration of all 3-connected non-isomorphic graphs on 7 vertices, that is, I would like to see **drawings** of them. I found a paper by CVETKOVIC which gives all 112 connected graphs on $6$ vertices. Hence, I distilled the 18 graphs which are 3-connected. I did not find anything similar for 7 vertices. So, is there one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out https://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-ConnectedGraph.html

There is a table that gives the numbers of $k$-connected graphs for $n$-vertex ($n$-node) graphs.

[image]

As you can see there are $17$ graphs on $6$ vertices and $136$ graphs on $7$ vertices that are $3$-connected. So, if you want to see these graphs *drawn*, then I guess that you want to do something manually which is probably possible for the $17$ graphs on $6$ vertices but I suspect it would be hard to do for all $136$ graphs on $7$ vertices. So, pictures or no pictures perhaps does not matter much.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly, you are correct. But now I know - I just did not find the page at Wolfram's.